# Index Out of Range Error in Swift

Tags: swift, breakpoints

```
var numberOfPeople = 1 //get from host
var numberAtCounter = 0
func showNames() {

    if peopleInMatch[numberAtCounter] == yourPeerID { //change to peopleinmatcheveryone

        if numberOfPeople == 0 {
            print("hoho")
            personName.isHidden = true
            connect.isHidden = false
            connect.setTitle("PRESS READY", for: UIControlState.normal)
            //change label to ready
        } else {
            numberAtCounter += 1
            numberOfPeople -= 1 // buggy?
            print("\(numberAtCounter)")
            showNames()
        }


    } else {
    personName.text = "TAKE PHOTO OF \(peopleInMatch[numberAtCounter])'s COLOR"
    numberAtCounter += 1
        if numberOfPeople <= 0 {
            personName.isHidden = true
            connect.isHidden = false
            connect.setTitle("PRESS READY", for: UIControlState.normal)
            //change label to ready
        }
    numberOfPeople -= 1 //buggy maybe fixed

    }
}
```

I'm getting a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT error on the  if peopleInMatch[numberAtCounter] == yourPeerID line. I'm not entirely sure what out of index means or what is potentially wrong. The code will be run through once then the function calls itself and on the second time through it breaks down on the line I mentioned above. I've checked all the variables and none of them are nill. Any ideas?

Comment: check "peopleInMatch" array size. It seems that peopleInMatch[1] doesn't exists.

Comment: If `numberAtCounter` is equal to or greater than the number of objects in your `peopleInMatch` array, then you get the crash due to the "index out of range" error. You need to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made a short example for you to understand where your problem actually is.

ScreenShot 1:

[image]

Everything works fine when function is called for first time value at numberAtCounter is printed.

Here in first call either you are decrementing the value as `numberAtCounter-=1` which take value from 0 to -1. Thus in second call when the function is called in line at:

```
if peopleInMatch[numberAtCounter] == yourPeerID // here you need to check value of `numberAtCounter`
```

make sure it's not getting a negative value or value more than your peopleInMatch array.

Thus if it becomes negative or more than count, result you will get as follows:

[image]